# Find all folders excluding some paths

Tags: visual-studio, regex, visual-studio-2008

In visual studio when searching for files, how can I find all files that do not contain a certain string in their directory path or file name?

For example:

I want to find all files that have the word MainRegion but I do not want files such as:

```
c:\myfiles\file1Fixture.cs
c:\myfiles\somedirectory\a.b.tests\filename.xaml
```

So I want to exclude file names with "Fixture" in and directory paths with "tests" in.

JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^.*\\[^\\]*Fixture[^\\]*$
```

should match files that contain `Fixture` in the file name (but not in the path).

```
^.*tests.*\\[^\\]*$
```

should match files that contain `tests` in the path, but not in the filename.

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio. Are you sure that it can use regexes to search for filenames?